# PHP & VS Code: inspect entire workspace for warnings, errors and etc

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have faced with problem when I changed some code in one .php file and broke some code in other one but I haven't noticed it because VS Code didn't show any errors in my workspace till I opened error causing file myself. Are there any solutions for that? I want configure VS Code so that will scan entire PHP folder for errors, not only opened as tabs files.

[image: My PHP project with error causing file in it (but file is not opened)]

[image: Errors appearing only when I opened file]